# CLLocationManager best practices

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm using a `CLLocationManager` (`_locationManager`) to track user location within my tab application to enable tracking movement in the background. There is a record button, which when pressed, begins tracking and drawing a polyline of the user's movements. The `[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` is called in `viewDidLoad` of the `MapViewController` within my `UITabBarController`. Is it best practice to tell the `_locationManager` to stop updating the location when the user switches to another tab (If the application is not recording)? Or should I let it keep going? The reason I ask is because i use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` if enabled in the settings, and I know there are battery concerns if left to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one basic rule: if you need the data, then keep it on, else, turn it off.